# Android SlidingDrawer close with custom animation

Tags: android, animation, slidingdrawer

I want to close the slidingDrawer with animation programmatically. I've got the following code:

```
SliderAnimationDown = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, sliderHeight - handleHeight);
SliderAnimationDown.setDuration(1000);

SliderAnimationDown.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(
{
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
    {
        slide.close();
    }
});

slide.startAnimation(SliderAnimationDown);
```

It is working, but you can see blinking (right after the animation ends and before slide is actually closed). I tried to call slide.setAnimation(SliderAnimationDown) and then slide.animateClose() - but it does nothing. What should I do to perform custom animation on SlidingDrawer close?

Comment: Thanks, your example worked flawlessly for me.